# Installing an apk file received by email

Tags: android

I have finished my android app work and the apk is signed.I have to give the app to someone for whom I have made the app .If I am sending it as email attached will it be installed or not.I searched in the net but it gave me confusing answers.Is there any other better way to send the app.Please help me

Comment: sending app via mail doesnot install user have to install the app

Answer (score 1):

No it won't. The user has to activate installing apps from unknown sources in the settings and that he/she can install the attached app.

Better sign up on the Google Play Console publish you app in the alpha or beta stage and add the user as a tester. Than the user just has to become a tester and he/she can download the app from the play store

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to release multiple versions to your client regurlarly, you can try releasing it via *GooglePlay* alpha or beta release.

Advantage: You can track your app version and crash reports, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes 
First of all goto mobile Settings / Application / Settings and check the box next to Unknown sources option. then click on apk downloaded from email and install.

Answer (score 0):

I guess any mail service firstly will not let you attach .apk file to any mail.

Better store it on `cloud` service and access it from any where. also do not forget to set `allow files from unknown sources` in your android phone to true.